# What should be the sharding key for chat history

Tags: database, database-design

This is probably be opinion based question but I can't really find any resources related to this. So I'm designing a chat system. The system should keep the chat history as well, but assuming we have a lot have a lot of daily active users so there would be a million records for chat history I'm considering sharding the table but could not figured out what should be selected as a sharding key. I have one in my mind which is the `senderId+receiverId` as a sharding key which means that each user would have their own shard, number of shard equals to number of user, so a user would be able to retrieve their chat history very fast by searching on their own shard, but there are a lot of drawbacks that I could think of such as hotspots (where one user has a lot of chat history).

```
class Message {
   @PrimaryKey
   private UUID messageId;
   private UUID senderId;
   private UUID receiverId;
   private String message;
   private MetaData metaData; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a manufactured sharding key like `senderId+receiverId`, because in the general case a query won't know both `senderId` *and* `receiverId`.

The logical choices are *either* `senderId` *or* `receiverId`. If you more often look up messages knowing the sender shard by that, otherwise shard by the receiver.

Consider storing each message twice in separate tables `received_message` and `sent_message` sharding accordingly then splicing the results to give a quick picture of all messages for any given user.